# Is there an open source object relational mapper for android contacts?

Tags: android

Eventually I would like to have functionality in my app to add or remove a contact from a group by simply having something like this:

myContact.addToGroup(group);
myContact.removeFromGroup(group);

I see a path to get there, but don't want to reinvent the wheel.

I have searched a bit and found [ActiveAndroid](https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid) which looks interesting but I get the impression it only works on databases it can modify.  Does anyone know of anything that would make dealing with the contacts database a little easier?